# Keep component scrolled to bottom

Tags: reactjs

I have made a mini chat box on an application that sits about mid way down the site on the 3rd section. I'd like to have this chat box always scrolled to the bottom when people type. I am currently using the bellow:

**ChatMessage.js**

```
const messagesEndRef = useRef(null)
const scrollToBottom = () => {messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' })}
useEffect(scrollToBottom, [messageUser]);

return (
    <>
    <div className='text-left my-2 mx-2'>
        <span className={`inline-block pr-4 pl-2 py-2 ${messageClass} rounded-lg`}>
            <span className='text-xs'>{username}</span><br />
            <span className='text-md font-bold'>{text}</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
    </>
)
```

**ChatBox.js**

```
{messages && messages.map(msg => <ChatMessage key={msg.id} messages={msg} user={props.user} /> )}
```

This solution has an issue when the user is actually not on the chat box page. If the user is to scroll to the top or bottom of the website, each time a message occurs the user if forced up to the chat box. Is there a way that I can have just the chatbox itself scroll to bottom without affecting the users exploring the rest of the site?

I tried thinking of using an iFrame or something but that didn't seem like it would be the best solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think ChatBox component should have be set position: fixed and stay on bottom and user can minimize or expand ChatMessage component every they want chat or not.